# DataBase Desktop для Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi

Как в Delphi 2010 создать базу данных? В Delphi 7, раньше, было:

```
Tools -> DataBase Desktop
```

Но в 10-ой нет этой утилиты. У меня установлена 2010 Delphi, что делать? Подскажите, плз.,
если что нибудь в 10-ой делфи похожее на DataBase Desktop.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ставь 7ю =)

Если не ошибаюсь, то это компонент `IBScript` в закладке `InterBase`...

А вообще, используй `IBExpert` для простого, можно так сказать, визуального, создания базы данных и таблиц.

Answer (score 0):

Используй BDE